# how to generate Mathematica code into more-appealing LaTeX code?

Tags: equations, wolfram-mathematica

```
Subscript[R, c] (Subscript[m, d] (g+Overscript[y, ¨]) sin(Subscript[\[Alpha], c]+Subscript[\[Theta], 1])+Subscript[k, d] cos(Subscript[\[Alpha], c]+Subscript[\[Theta], 1]) (Subscript[d, c] cos(Subscript[\[Omega], c]+Subscript[\[Theta], 1])-Subscript[R, 1] sin(Subscript[\[Alpha], 1])))+Overscript[x, ¨] (Subscript[R, c] Subscript[m, d] cos(Subscript[\[Alpha], c]+Subscript[\[Theta], 1])+Subscript[m, 2] Subscript[R, 2] cos(Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]+Subscript[\[Theta], 1]))+Subscript[m, 2] Subscript[R, 2] sin(Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]+Subscript[\[Theta], 1]) (g+Overscript[y, ¨])<Subscript[\[Theta], 1]^\[Prime]\[Prime] (-Subscript[d, c] Subscript[R, c] Subscript[m, d] sin(Subscript[\[Alpha], c]-Subscript[\[Omega], c])+d Subscript[m, 2] Subscript[R, 2] sin(\[Omega]-Subscript[\[Alpha], 2])+Subscript[IG, 2])+(Subscript[\[Theta], 1]^\[Prime])^2 (Subscript[d, c] Subscript[R, c] Subscript[m, d] cos(Subscript[\[Alpha], c]-Subscript[\[Omega], c])+d Subscript[m, 2] Subscript[R, 2] cos(\[Omega]-Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]))
```

Comment: Did you try selecting, right clicking and then Copy as LaTeX? In this case it gives `R_c \left(\sin  m_d \left(\alpha _c+\theta _1\right) \left(g+\ddot{y}\right)+\cos  k_d \left(\alpha _c+\theta _1\right) \left(\cos  d_c \left(\omega _c+\theta _1\right)-\alpha _1 R_1 \sin \right)\right)+\ddot{x} \left(\cos  R_c m_d \left(\alpha _c+\theta _1\right)+m_2 R_2 \cos  \left(\alpha _2+\theta _1\right)\right)+m_2 R_2 \sin  \left(\alpha _2+\theta _1\right) \left(g+\ddot{y}\right)`

Comment: I believe there is also a command `Latex[%]` (or similar). BTW... Wonderful trick @HenriMenke